# Whats the difference between float and numeric in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, floating-point

Reading the Postgresql docs [about the numeric data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html)
leads me to this question:
why do I get these unexpected results with the data types `Float` (SQL standard) and `Numeric` in Postgresql?

For example:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE testnum (a numeric, b float);
INSERT INTO testnum VALUES (100,100);
INSERT INTO testnum VALUES (9*9*9,9*9*9);
INSERT INTO testnum VALUES (9^9^9,9^9^9);
SELECT (a/3)*3 AS numeric, (b/3) * 3 AS float FROM testnum;
SELECT (a/5)*5 AS numeric, (b/5) * 5 AS float FROM testnum;
```

Then run

```
SELECT (a/3)*3 AS numeric, (b/3) * 3 AS float FROM testnum;

numeric                                     |         float          
                        99.9999999999999999 |                    100
                       729.0000000000000000 |                    729
```

In this test `Float` looks more accurate than `Numeric`.

Which one is the appropriate data type for precise numeric values like currency or inventory quantities?

Comment: `numeric` is also an SQL standard data type.

Comment: when you get such numbers t alsways caused by fractals.And tehre lies the basuc difference how the numeric and floar are stored, but that should be covert in the manual

Comment: "*Which one is the appropriate data type for precise numeric values*" - clearly numeric. Related: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are falling victim of implicit type casts. When one of the operands is `numeric` and another one `integer`, the integer operand will be cast to `numeric` and the result will be `numeric`. Since `numeric` has a strictly defined precision, attempting to assign to it a value with infinitely many digits after the decimal point (which 100/3 produces), without rounding, will result in truncation. The same logic applies to multiplication, to which one operand now is *not* 33.333... (with an infinite sequence of "3"s) that you seem to expect, but rather a defined precision `numeric` 33.333...3 (a finite sequence of "3"s), which naturally produces 99.999...9 -- a finite sequence

When one of the operands is `float` and another one `integer`, the integer operand will be cast to `float` and the result will be `float`. Since `float` has an approximate precision, it is equipped to deal with 33.333... and 99.999... differently, which eventually results in an approximate value of 100.

As to

> Which one is the appropriate data type for precise numeric values like currency or inventory quantities?

the manual gives you the exact answer you need:

> If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead.

What it does *not* say is that you should control calculations at each step by using explicit type casting and rounding appropriate for your business rules.